# Documents to support a further application following the refusal of a Standard UK visa?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, visa-refusals

A couple of days ago I posted [Reapplying for a UK Standard Visitor visa after a refusal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52454/reapplying-for-a-uk-standard-visitor-visa-after-a-refusal) where I included the reasons for my being refused a UK Standard visa.  I am planning to re-apply but require further guidance before I proceed with another application.

My cousin and my friend both sent me a letter of invitation. I used my friend's letter for the initial application. I did write in the initial application that I will be visiting my cousin as well.

I did not submit my leave letter from work with the initial application.  I was granted leave for one month but now because of work requirements my company has cancelled some of my leave and granted me only 20 days.

- Can I use the same letter of invitation sent by my friend?
- Will it have negative impact if I use the letter sent by my cousin?
- If I submit my leave letter for 20 days and apply to visit for 20 days will it have adverse effect, as my initial application was for 30 days?

Comment: 1. How long should i wait to reapply again? 2.I only asked if I can use,  I did not say I will.  I am only trying to clear all my doubts as much as I can as I am very confuse now after the first refusal what's the right thing to do.

Comment: From [here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52454/reapplying-for-a-uk-standard-visitor-visa-after-a-refusal)  "I don't predict a favourable outcome if you apply again right away. You need a substantive change in circumstances and evidence that you are leading an independent life. If you apply again right away, they will refuse again and then matters will be worse."  So yes, clearing your doubts is fine at this stage. But be cautious about filing your next application back-to-back :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of the items you mentioned can go in Part 9 of the form (Additional Information).

For a best practices approach, you can use a template along these lines...

> **Change of Circumstances**
>
> 1. (explain change of host here)
> 2. (explain change of leave here)
> 3. (explain other changes since your previous application here)

You can also use a separate sheet attached to your application instead of the form.  You can do this if the list is long.

Doing this will help avoid any awkward questions arising from why and how things have changed since your previous application.  They like it when changes are listed in a well organized and transparent manner, so try to get all of them listed.  Following a previous refusal, the more changes in circumstances you can list, the better your application will be received.

Comment: Can I chat with you if it is okay?

Comment: @April, you can ping me from the main chat room. I would avoid the private rooms.