# After refusals should I apply again (UK visitor visa)

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-of-ties, serial-refusals

Is there any way to visit my partner and my first newborn? I have not seen her for a long time.

I have 5 refusals for "Visitor Visas" and she can't come to algeria as borders are still closed and there is no flights.

Shall I apply again and tell them that I want to see my baby, or will they just refuse again since I have the past refusals?

Comment: Why have you been refused 5 times, have they all been for the same reason? Unless you improve whatever the previous issues were you are likely to just be refused again. Remember you need to show strong ties to your home country to prove you will not overstay your visit.

Comment: first two applications I've applied with my father from long time ago , they refused his application so ECO said I have to refuse ur application too cuz u cant go without sponsor ... and other ones ECO said : you have no dependants or other immediate personal family ties in your home country (my wife was in uk ) still don't understand

Comment: Related question (possible duplicate) https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88850/what-exactly-does-the-uk-consulate-mean-by-change-of-application-circumstance Is your wife a British citizen or legally resident in the UK? What ties to Algeria *do* you have that would convince an ECO that you will leave your family behind and go back to Algeria at the end of your visit?

Comment: yes my wife she is a british citizen and my daughter too....the only strong ties that I have atm is my job and studies .

Comment: These comments, explaining the refusals, should be intergrated into the question. These explantions are the reason why the UK believes that you will not return. An application to join your family permanenty is more likley to be successfull than a visitor visa.

Comment: @MarkJohnson she doesnt financial requirements atm , she just gave a birth
.. Thanks for ur help