# UK visa refusal for GMC ID check

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

Well i have been refused 3rd time now for no reason though i provide each possible supporting documents regarding last refusal..but still they refused for

1. lack of funds though i have 10 times more funfs in the statement provided
2. Despite giving all the reference for current job still they aren't satisfied whether i am doing a job or not.

Please advise.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide the exact wording of the refusals and what you want help with. If you’ve been refused three times, there must be a reason why - either you are not providing appropriate and suitable evidence, or you do not meet the eligibility criteria, or your circumstances haven’t changed sufficiently https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88850/what-exactly-does-the-uk-consulate-mean-by-change-of-application-circumstance

Comment: Please tell how to enter the refusal image here?

Comment: Take a photo of the refusal notice. Then modify the image to obscure your personal details (name, address, etc.). Save the modified image. Then press the "Edit" button below your question text, and then press the "Moon and Mountains" button that appears at the top of the text entry box. You can then upload the modified image from your computer onto this site; the image will appear within your question.