# PLAB 2 visa refusal

Tags: visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

[image: letter]  [image: refusal]

I had applied for a visa for PLAB 2, which got refused based on the grounds that I wasn't employed for one year after my graduation and was unemployed. The fact was I was doing my internship which finished in August (I applied for my visa in December). I was not having my internship certificate at that time which I have now. So they were not satisfied that I will return back.

I have my internship certificate now, showing that I have been working as an intern for the past year, though I am unemployed now (as we require internship certificate for applying for jobs in UAE and for getting registration, basically for everything). I also will take the residency entrance examination for UAE but the applications for this only open in April and I intend to apply for that too when the dates are announced but meanwhile want to clear my PLAB 2 examination.

Can anyone guide me on now how to progress further so that my visa application doesn't get rejected?

Comment: The refusal indicates that your application lacked proof that you plan to return home from the UK. It is your responsibility to convince the officer handling your request that this is the case. A job would be a good place to start, as would completing the residency requirements you mentioned. Unless you can provide sufficient evidence to convince the officer, you will need to postpone the trip until your circumstances change enough to provide a good case that you will return to your country of residence after the trip.

Comment: And especially read this one! http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52454/reapplying-for-a-uk-standard-visitor-visa-after-a-refusal/52492#52492